# How to run part or whole of a posh scriptblock or file based on condition

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, taskscheduler

I am kind of stuck in figuring this out.

I have read-only access to certain scripts that can run for hours.
Unfortunately, the environment permissions only allows me to use the task-scheduler, and often I need to stop a script from running when a condition WHILE the script is running is true, where the script must be halted immediately.

for example say:

$Variable = 2 after whatever calculation and processing it did.

I need to stop the task from continuing

What can I add in the argument field to do so.

do, while/until dont work since they are loops and will let the whole script finish rather than stopping based on the condition.

Comment: when your test indicates the exit condition is met ... use `exit`. [*grin*] it's a reserved word that forces the script to exit/end/kill-itself. lookee ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6#exit

Comment: Thanks. I, actually tried that. It wont work since it still relies on the while/until ... or maybe I am just structuring the arguments wrong, since it still completes a single loop of the whole script before exiting. I am more trying to figure out what I can use to see the variables in the running script block and block them when they equal something and exit then...

Comment: if the script is NOT exiting ... then the `exit` keyword is not being reached in your code. without seeing the code - or at least the logic outline of your code - no one can tell why the `exit` keyword is not being reached.

Answer (score 1):

A script block is an all of nothing thing by design. You can break / exit any script/scriptblock via a condition match using the break or / exit keywords.

If you are trying to break/exit out of a script/scriptblock, then that scriptblock has to have logic to deal with a condition check that allows that. So, try/catch - do/while, etc, are all still prudent

[About Language Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6)
Describes the keywords in the PowerShell scripting language.

> ***Break*** Describes a statement you can use to immediately exit Foreach, For, While, Do, or Switch statements.
>
> ***Exit*** Causes PowerShell to exit a script or a PowerShell instance.

```
$i = 3
while ($true) {
  trap [DivideByZeroException] {
    Write-Host 'divide by zero trapped'
    break
  }
   1 / $i--
}
```

See also
[PowerShell: Tips for terminating code execution](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/powershell-terminating-code-execution)

[ScriptBlock Flexibility in PowerShell](https://www.hofferle.com/scriptblock-flexibility-in-powershell)